# CALDAV Share Calendar by curl

Tags: curl, owncloud, caldav

For a project I need to create shares on a owncloud dav server. I can create and share folders via dav, I can create calendars but not share them. I tried to make post request to:
[https://example.dav/remote.php/dav/calendar/[PRINCIPAL]/[CALENDAR]/](https://example.dav/remote.php/dav/calendar/%5BPRINCIPAL%5D/%5BCALENDAR%5D/)

with post data:

```
<o:share xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:a="http://apple.com/ns/ical/" xmlns:o="http://owncloud.org/ns" xmlns:n="http://nextcloud.com/ns" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
    <o:set>
        <d:href>
            principal:principals/groups/[GROUP]
        </d:href>
        <o:summary>
            [GROUP] geteilt von [PRINCIPAL]
        </o:summary>
    </o:set>
</o:share>
```

the answer I got from the server is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
    <s:exception>
        Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotImplemented
    </s:exception>
    <s:message>
        There was no handler found for this "POST" method
    </s:message>
</d:error>
```

which makes me wonder, since the webfrontend e.g. exactly makes this call to share an calendar object.

Comment: Please embed the full transcript of your curl call as well as a transcript of the matching webui call. That share call you are doing is not CalDAV, but sth oc specific. Real CalDAV sharing is done using properties on the calendar collections.

Comment: you could take a look at `OwnCloudService::postCalendarItemToServer` in https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/blob/develop/src/services/owncloudservice.cpp how I do it there... (but I only create / edit / remove calendar items)

Comment: Patrizios Solution does not help for sharing - but sharing is my point.

Comment: hnh, since my time is quite limited, i beg you to wait untill i can start my tests again (several projects ...). Since the dav backend behind the owncloud is sabre/dav, i would suggest, it would be rather an sabre specific call than an owncloud specific.

Comment: I finally hacked the problem by bypassing it. Since my solution was following https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pot-webdav-resource-sharing-03 also, i believe this could be a bug either in the owncloud as the container of sabre/dav or sabre/dav.